# Non-repetitive permutation possible query in mongoDB ? _ mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose

suppose we have array of ids and we need to query with condition of :

1.exact match of single ids

2. only exact possible permutation of ids

like this:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

**result** :

```
[
  {foo:["a"]},
  {foo:["a", "b"]},
  {foo:["a", "c"]},
  {foo:["b", "c"]},
  {foo:["a", "b", "c"]},
  {foo:["c"]},
  {foo:["b"]},
]
```

and **not** this :

```
[
  {foo:["a"]},
  {foo:["a", "b"]},
  {foo:["a", "f"]},
  {foo:["g", "c"]},
  {foo:["a", "b", "f"]},
]
```

> for the record, now I have a premutation function that makes for me
> these arrays before the query step, and I am using for loop for iterating in my results.

but this function is gonna blow my performance. this is not efficient

for every index in my array, I have factorial possibilities.

```
4! = 4 × 3 × 2 × 1 = 24
7! = 7 × 6 × 5 × 4 × 3 × 2 × 1 = 5,040
```

what should I do?

Comment: Yep, math can be brutal. I suggest using another way of storing the data. Try hashing? Each combination can be encoded into bit strings and then you will have a linear search time.